# What is the procedure when being pulled over for a known officer?

Tags: traffic, regulations

I have my own opinions about what is best for you to do when getting pulled over. I am hoping I may have missed anything I could add. What are things that a driver can do to make the stop as seamless as possible for them. What shouldn't you do that get under the officers skin that is common but may not be illegal so I don't?

I am hoping someone in traffic law enforcement can answer but anyone is welcomed.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is a question about personal behaviour, not the law or legal process.

Comment: If this question does not belong in law, where does it belong?

Answer (score 2):

Understand what behaviors alarm officers and what puts them at ease:

- Keep your hands in plain sight (steering wheel)
- keep your registration in your visor and have your documents ready
- reaching into the glove box for your registration?  put yourself in the officers shoes...
- Be calm and mind your tone: officers are always wary of not surviving
- Smile: be friendly, polite & demonstrate Emotional Intelligence
- Practicing the golden rule usually results in the best possible outcome
- Keep answers short and to the point: Yes / No  / IDK officer ....

Officers want to go home and avoid  the morgue / hospital.  If you do not know 'the drill' it would be worth your time.   Unfortunately, stereotypes and bias come into play.

Did the officer touch your car (put his print on your paint job)?  Read the bullet points again because you are high risk suspect.